# Find and remove files in multiple directories

Tags: bash, centos, command-line-interface

Right now I have a cron job that runs once a week to find and remove files for me that have accumulated during that time. It goes something like this:

```
find $DIR1 -maxdepth 1 \( -name \file1-\* -o -name \*file2-\* \) -mtime +7 >> /tmp/file.txt
```

However, I want to do the same thing in another directory on the server (must be $DIR1 and $DIR2 - doing a find from root across the whole system isn't viable) but I feel that, while repeating the command would work, it would be ugly, redundant and inefficient.

So, I want to build a list somehow (i.e. FILES="file1 file2 file3") and have a streamlined method of checking both directories and then outputting the results of what's found to the text file like above.

I'm not certain of how to do this - I've thought of perhaps doing a loop, but that seems too basic. Can anyone throw me a bone here and point me in the right direction? The big thing I'm worried about is getting this to work with find.

Edit: To clarify, the second search in $DIR2 is for files older than 14 days (mtime +14) so just adding $DIR2 into the existing string won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
find $DIR1 $DIR2 -maxdepth 1 \( -name \file1-\* -o -name \*file2-\* \) -mtime +7 >> /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: Oh right, I should have specified - the second search needs to be for 14 days, so simply appending $DIR2 into the same command won't work as far as I know since I can only search for either 7 days or 14 days, but not both within the same string.

Comment: In that case I think two find commands will be the most efficient. Otherwise you will have search for files older than 7 days in both and cull the false positives found in DIR2

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to write a bash script i.e. delete_files.sh and add the bash script in crontab. So next time, if you want to add any more patterns with different directories then you just have to write in bash script only and it will be added in cronjob automatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo $(find $DIR1 $DIR2 -maxdepth 1 \( -name \file1-\* -o -name \*file2-\* \) -mtime +7) >> /tmp/file.txt;
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo $(find $DIR1 -maxdepth 1 \( -name \file1-\* -o -name \*file2-\* \) -mtime +7) >> /tmp/file.txt;
echo $(find $DIR2 -maxdepth 1 \( -name \file1-\* -o -name \*file2-\* \) -mtime +7) >> /tmp/file.txt;
```